# Por quê o $.post() não retorna um objeto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu tenho uma função mais ou menos assim:

```
$('#btn-load-more').click(function(){
    var key = $('#hash').val(), limit = 0, i = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post('api', {type: 1, limit: limit, key: 128921}, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Só que o problema, é que ao clicar no botão e acionar o evento, o resultado no console é exatamente assim:

```
[{"title":"Título de teste","thumb":"2","views":"920134"},{"title":"lorem 
ipsum teste inskl","thumb":"2","views":"920134"}]
```

Quando o resultado deveria ser varios objetos. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
    ▼ 0: Object
        thumb: "2"
        title: "Título de teste"
        views: "920134"
    ▶ 1: Object
```

Mas o meu objetivo era retornar um objeto, como acontece quando eu mudo o `$.post` para `$.getJSON`, o que eu tô fazendo de errado?

Comment: Defina o quarto parâmetro de `$.post` como `"json"`. Por padrão, ele é `string`, por isso seu resultado não é convertido para objeto. Só ler a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: Valeu cara, nossa! um problema tão fácil!

Answer (score 4):

Por padrão, a função `$.post` possui um quarto parâmetro que define o tipo de retorno. Por padrão, o jQuery tentará descobrir qual é o tipo, sendo suscetível à falhas:

```
$.post(url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType = "Intelligent Guess" ] );
```

Ou seja, se não alterado, o retorno poderá ser qualquer formato, como no seu caso um texto bruto. Como o seu retorno é um JSON, basta você alterar explicitamente este valor para `"json"`, que seu resultado chegará como um objeto JavaScript:

```
$('#btn-load-more').click(function(){
    var key = $('#hash').val(), limit = 0, i = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post('api', {type: 1, limit: limit, key: 128921}, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }, "json");
    }, 500);
});
```

Conforme a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), este parâmetro aceita: `"xml"`, `"json"`, `"script"`, `"text"` e `"html"`.

Answer (score 1):

A solução adequada é a [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208573/32827) resposta, porém existe outra alternativa que é [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var txt = '[{"title":"Título de teste","thumb":"2","views":"920134"},{"title":"lorem ipsum teste inskl","thumb":"2","views":"920134"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
console.log(obj);
```