# erro json php, porem json está correto

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Meu script php retorna um json, porˆm quando o js vai ler o json acusa erro.
[image: erro json]

Mas copiando e colando o mesmo json num validador (ex: https://jsonlint.com/) diz estar correto.

Para quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Edit: segue json

```
{"ArrayTopFiveItens":[{"Cod_Item":"1","Nome_Comercial":"Coca-Cola Lata","Foto":""},{"Cod_Item":"2","Nome_Comercial":"Coca-Cola KS","Foto":""},{"Cod_Item":"3","Nome_Comercial":"Agua com gas","Foto":""},{"Cod_Item":"4","Nome_Comercial":"Cerveja 600 ML","Foto":""},{"Cod_Item":"5","Nome_Comercial":"Cerveja litro","Foto":""}],"ArrayComandas":[{"Cod_Comanda":"1","Descricao":"Comanda","Nome_Interno":"1","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"1","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"1","Nome":"Rafael","CPF":"06282724996","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":""}},{"Ref_Comanda":"1","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"2","Nome":"Rafael","CPF":"06282724996","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":""}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"info","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0},{"Cod_Comanda":"2","Descricao":"Comanda","Nome_Interno":"2","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"2","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"2","Nome":"Rafael","CPF":"06282724996","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":""}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"success","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0},{"Cod_Comanda":"3","Descricao":"Comanda","Nome_Interno":"3","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"3","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"3","Nome":"Joao","CPF":"","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":""}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"dark","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0},{"Cod_Comanda":"4","Descricao":"teste","Nome_Interno":"4","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"4","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"4","Nome":"Teste a","CPF":"69454976826","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":"47999285532"}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"info","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0},{"Cod_Comanda":"5","Descricao":"wsdf","Nome_Interno":"5","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"5","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"4","Nome":"Teste a","CPF":"69454976826","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":"47999285532"}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"dark","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0},{"Cod_Comanda":"6","Descricao":"teste","Nome_Interno":"6","Utilizadores":[{"Ref_Comanda":"6","Fechamento_Forcado":0,"ObjPessoa":{"Cod_pessoa":"4","Nome":"Teste a","CPF":"69454976826","Reponsavel_Financeiro":"0","Email":"","Telefone":"47999285532"}}],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":"1","Cor":"info","Atualiza_Painel":"0","TotalComanda":0}],"permissaoCLIENT":true,"NomeArquivoImpressao":"","NomeImpressora":"","TemImpressao":false,"ComandaFechada":{"Cod_Comanda":null,"Descricao":"","Nome_Interno":null,"Utilizadores":[],"Itens":[],"Requer_Utilizador":1,"Cor":"primary","Atualiza_Painel":true,"TotalComanda":0},"Cod_Item_Venda_Direta":0,"Nome_Interno_Venda_Direta":" ","Preco_Venda_Venda_Direta":0,"Quantidade_Venda_Direta":0,"Abre_Venda_Direta":0,"DigitoVerificadorAutomatico":"","Alerta":true,"StatusOperacao":true,"MSGOperacao":"","InexistenteException":false}
```

Codigo JS primeira parte:

```
  $.post('./assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' ,  Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){
       VerificaNotificacao("ao Limpar Formulario",x,true);
       popular(x);
       ModalClose();
       FocusCampo('.primeiro');

  });
```

Funcao VerificaNotificacao

```
function VerificaNotificacao(acao,json,somenteError){
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        DigitoVerificadorAutomatico = obj.DigitoVerificadorAutomatico;
        if(DigitoVerificadorAutomatico == 0){
            $('.dig').attr('readonly','readonly');
        }else{
            $('.dig').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
        if(obj.Alerta === true){
            if(obj.StatusOperacao === true){
                if(!somenteError){
                    Notificacao("Sucesso ","Sucesso "+acao,"success");
                }
                return true;
            }else{
                Notificacao("Ocorreu um erro","Erro "+acao+"\nErro: "+obj.MSGOperacao,'error');
                return false;
            }
        }
  }
```

o erro ocorre nesta linha  `var obj = JSON.parse(json);`

**Obrigado a todos que ajudaram**

Comment: segue foto do validador https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDPoS.png

Comment: Pode colocar o texto JSON na pergunta? ( atualmente só está a imagem)

Comment: coloquei no post pois excede o comprimento da resposta, copiei e colei do meu debuger

Comment: os caras vão negativando sem nem entender o que está acontecendo. Mande o código js para avaliarmos melhor. Ou edite o post com o código js que retorna este erro.

Comment: sim verdade, sei que e um assunto bem batido, mas procurei bem antes de postar.  assim meu sistema e meio complexo sao muitos codigo mas vou tentar postar  a principal parte do erro

Comment: a função não ta ficando dentro da marcação

Comment: Tenta colocar JSON.stringify() na primeira parte 
 $.post('./assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' ,  Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){
       VerificaNotificacao("ao Limpar Formulario",JSON.stringify(x),true);

Comment: Eu tentei e não funcionou.

Comment: Rafael, tente assim: `$.post( './assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' ,  Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){ .... }, "json");`

Comment: fiz oque o @Everson falou e passou tudo certo, mas estou com duvida, pois tenho outras telas que utilizam a mesma função e nao Ocorre o erro oque poderia ser ?

Comment: +1 pra pergunta, esse é um tipo de problema que muita gente tem com jQuery e sei que ela será útil para futuros visitantes ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que o jQuery especificamente já faz o "parse" para *Json automaticamente* conforme é descrito em:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType

  > The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

O padrão é "adivinhação inteligente", ou seja o jQuery tenta adivinha o conteúdo da resposta, ainda mais se o `Content-type` estiver definido para algo como `application/json` (o que deve ajudar na "adivinhação"), creio que esteja usando jQuery devido a isto:

```
$.post(...
```

Então não é necessário:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Basta fazer algo como:

```
var obj = json;
```

Claro que você pode forçar o comportamento como texto e fazer o parse depois:

```
$.post('./assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' ,  Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){
   VerificaNotificacao("ao Limpar Formulario",x,true);
   popular(x);
   ModalClose();
   FocusCampo('.primeiro');
}, "text"); //Definido como texto
```

Ou forçar json e remover o `JSON.parse`, assim:

```
$.post('./assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' ,  Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){
   VerificaNotificacao("ao Limpar Formulario",x,true);
   popular(x);
   ModalClose();
   FocusCampo('.primeiro');
}, "json"); //Força o proprio jQuery fazer o parse

function VerificaNotificacao(acao,json,somenteError){
    var obj = json;//Sem json parse

    DigitoVerificadorAutomatico = obj.DigitoVerificadorAutomatico;
    if(DigitoVerificadorAutomatico == 0){
        $('.dig').attr('readonly','readonly');
    }else{
        $('.dig').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
    if(obj.Alerta === true){
        if(obj.StatusOperacao === true){
            if(!somenteError){
                Notificacao("Sucesso ","Sucesso "+acao,"success");
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            Notificacao("Ocorreu um erro","Erro "+acao+"\nErro: "+obj.MSGOperacao,'error');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fiz oque você sugeriu, não deu erro, porem quando vou recuperar um dos dados retorna  undefined

Comment: @RafaelVitordaSilva ótimo, resolvemos o problema principal, agora esse undefined é outro erro, provavelmente alguma coisa que vc fez errada, poderia dizer qual variavel esta acusando `undefined` para eu tentar corrigir?

Comment: @RafaelVitordaSilva se não conseguir ver o que retornou undefined adiciona isto ao teu código `var obj = json; console.log(obj);` e então no console do navegador pega a resposta e me manda ;)

Comment: fiz oque o @Everson falou e passou tudo certo, mas estou com duvida, pois tenho outras telas que utilizam a mesma função e nao dao erro oque poderia ser ?

Comment: $.post( './assets/classes/Controller.Controller.php', {acao: 'new' , Controller: controller , data:data}, function(x){ .... }, "json");     adicionei no final  , "json")

Comment: @RafaelVitordaSilva é o que eu disse, o jQuery tenta fazer "adivinhação inteligente", ainda mais se o `Content-type` estiver definido para algo como `application/json`, o que o Everson falou foi o mesmo que eu disse, forçar o parametro `dataType` (claro que eu sugeri usar como `text` para poder usar o json.parse), mas de qualquer forma o problema todo é devido ao *Intelligent Guess* do jQuery ;) ... Atualizei a resposta pra ficar canônica https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209200/3635

Comment: coloquei  text como você me indicou e não precisei alterar mais nada ou seja para mim, a sua reposta foi exatamente oque eu precisava, Obrigado pela Ajuda.

Comment: @RafaelVitordaSilva por nada, se puder marcar como correta eu ficaria grato também :D, se não souber como fazer isto, aqui tem um guia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635 Até mais

Answer (score 1):

O erro está relacionado ao `JSON.parse` no seu código javascript.

Isso pode acontecer ao tentar parsear um JSON inválido, mas como no seu exemplo o JSON está valido, certifique-se se você não está tentando parsear um JSON já parseado:

```
var res = JSON.parse('{"key":"value"}'); // Sucesso, faz o parse JSON de uma string
var res = JSON.parse({"key":"value"}) // Erro, pois o JSON já é um objeto javascript
```

Neste caso, o jQuery já retorna a resposta como um JSON parseado, então não é necessário o `JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: Eu realizei um teste, dando alert no retorno json e um obj json para comparar a diferenca dos dois

function VerificaNotificacao(acao,json,somenteError){
        alert(json);
        var a = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"} ;
        alert(a);
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
}

alert(json)  ===  Gerou uma String 
alert(a);     === Gerou um Objeto [Object][Object]

Acredito que o json esta vindo uma String mesmo. (Nao sei afirmar se meu teste serve para excluir a possibilidade de estar acontecendo oque voce disse)

Comment: Dei alert com typeof e esta vindo String mesmo o json

Comment: Você pode tentar colocar o parâmetro `dataType` no ajax do `$.post`. Assim você diz que o retorno esperado é do tipo json. Daí ficaria mais ou menos assim: `$.post(url, dados, function() { ... }, 'json');`. Mais informações na documentação https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208564/por-qu%C3%AA-o-post-n%C3%A3o-retorna-um-objeto

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei caracteres como \r\n no seu json. Tente os remover no php antes de passar para variável. Sugestão:

```
$json = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", ' ', $json);
```

Simulei seu código testando só essa parte com problema, alterando onde há \r\n por /r/n e não tenho mais erro.
https://jsfiddle.net/6baw5gqp/

Comment: retirei o \r\n no jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/6baw5gqp/5/) esta passando ok sem erros porem no meu continua dando erro com o novo json, atualizei o json do topico

Comment: não entendi rafael. Vc substituiu no fiddle o json que estava lá, pelo que vc atualizou no tópico e voltou a aparecer o erro??